# Sublime Text 3 slow sidebar over sshfs

Tags: linux, sftp, sublime-text-3

I'm checking out Sublime Text 3 since I'm looking to replace my current text editor, I need something that runs natively on Ubuntu.

Sublime Text 3 seems to be what I want, but I'm a very heavy SFTP user.

Currently I use EditPad Pro which supports SFTP extremely well. There I hold connections open to the roots of multiple servers (but not as the root user, with the home dir as the starting point), while I switch among the servers and open the files I want to edit.

The Sublime SFTP plugin is ridiculous in comparison to EditPad Pro's SFTP handling and is clearly not an option. If I understand it correctly, it would sync the entire remote directory locally, if I use the folder mapping mode.

What comes very close to the feeling I get with EditPad Pro is mounting the remote machine via sshfs to a local folder, and then edit the files as if they were local.  The only thing I then lose is the server selection list, since all servers are on the same filesystem as a folder, so no quick switching between machines. I can live with that.

Now, the problem is that if I mount the home directory of a machine, and this home directory has lots of stuff in it, even mounts to other systems, for some reason Sublime Text is traversing the entire home directory, instead of just listing the current level. I even get some inode errors and that there is no more space avaliable, which is very strange.

Ideally Sublime Text would not parse that remote directory at all, but just show what's there. I have no Git plugins installed, and set `"index_files": false,`, but the icons in the sidebar keep pulsating as indicating that something is getting traversed. I occasionally see some log entries regarding virtualenvs on the remote machine, as if it is trying to build an index for Python linting/intellisense stuff which I don't need.

When I open a file, I can edit along without any problem, and it syncs back relatively fast, just as fast as EditPad Pro does.

Is there something I can disable in Sublime Text in order for it to not go around looking what is in the subfolders?

Comment: See https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/long-lockups-when-using-remote-file-systems/30796